# MUI Datepicker how to disable next month only

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using MUI v5 and I want to disable next month only in datepicker. Others are available

Comment: Cannot you just use the prop `shouldDisableDate`.
https://mui.com/x/api/date-pickers/date-picker/#main-content

Comment: can u show me how to use??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import moment from 'moment';

const isNextMonth = (date) = {
  const startOfNextMonth = moment().add(1, 'month').startOf('month');
  const endOfNextMonth = moment().add(1, 'month').endOf('month');
  return date >= startOfNextMonth && date <= endOfNextMonth;
};

<LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
  <DatePicker
    views={['year', 'month', 'day']}
    label={label}
    shouldDisableDate={isNextMonth}
    value={value}
    onChange={handleChange}
    renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} helperText={null} />}
  />
</LocalizationProvider>
```